# How to change “selected” value using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change “selected” value in combobox using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778184/how-to-change-selected-value-in-combobox-using-javascript)

So here's my code"

```
<label class="conl">Pokaż wyniki jako
<br><select name="show_as">
<option value="topics">Wątki</option>
<option value="posts">Posty</option>
</select>
<br></label>
```

How to change default selection (from topics to posts)?
I can NOT modify this part of HTML code in any way, but I can add a script anywhere inside the head.

Comment: If you can use jQuery, then take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496052/jquery-setting-the-selected-value-of-a-select-control-via-its-text-description

Answer (score 0):

Try it (have not tested):

```
 var doprdown = document.getElementsByName('show_as')[0];
 for(var i = 0; i < dropdown.options.length; i++){
     if(dropdown.options[i].value == "posts")
          dropdown.selectedIndex = i;
 }
```

Or jQuery:

```
$("select[name='show_as'] > option[value=posts]").attr('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

***Jquery Code:***

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
$('#show_as').val('posts');
});
</script>
```

***Html code:***

here i have specified an id in-order to select the select box called "show_as"

```
 <label class="conl">Pokaż wyniki jako
<br><select name="show_as" id="show_as">
<option value="topics">Wątki</option>
<option value="posts">Posty</option>
</select>
<br></label>
```